# How can I resolve various warnings during compilation of my React app?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, compiler-warnings, react-typescript

I got these warnings in my react project:
(The packages in the `node_module` folder are up-to-date.)

How can I solve these warnings?

> /src/index.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css) Warning
>
> (309:5) start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start
> instead printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:138

> ./src/index.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css) Warning
>
> (457:5) Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like `to left` instead of `right`.

> ./src/index.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css) Warning
>
> (477:5) Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like `to left` instead of `right`.

> ./src/index.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css) Warning
>
> (497:5) Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like `to left` instead of `right`.

Comment: Each one has resolution notes under it. What's the question?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that almost any NPM project has at least a few warnings. They're usually not really a problem for the end user, but should be addressed by the vendor.

Comment: I received these warnings and now I want to get rid of it.

Comment: "These warnings" are many different issues. You need to ask something more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `top` I have used `to bottom` value.

[Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like "to left" instead of "right".](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/530#issuecomment-143785816)